# Aurelia CLI Run Command in ASP.NET Core Project Producing Only CannotGET

Tags: asp.net-core, aurelia

I have created a new ASP.NET Core Web API project and then run the au new --here command selecting option 2 (ASP.NET Core Project) to create a starting point for a web application.

Next I updated the Startup.cs file to serve static files.

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseFileServer();
```

Finally I updated the aurelia.json file to build into the wwwroot folder.

```
"platform": {
    "id": "aspnetcore",
    "displayName": "ASP.NET Core",
    "output": "wwwroot/scripts",
    "index": "wwwroot/index.html",
    "baseUrl": "scripts"
},

"build": {
    "targets": [
      {
        "id": "aspnetcore",
        "displayName": "ASP.NET Core",
        "output": "wwwroot/scripts",
        "index": "wwwroot/index.html",
        "baseUrl": "scripts"
      }
],
```

The Aurelia CLI will run the build option (au build) and the run option (au run) fine and it will serve up the site on http://localhost:9000.  But I get only the following HTML served up:

```
<html><head></head><body>CannotGET /</body></html>
```

or if trying to reference http://localhost:9000/index.html

```
<html><head></head><body>CannotGET /index.html</body></html>
```

If I run the application through Visual Studio and IIS Express it works fine.

*What am I missing to get au run to work?*

I have the same result with ASP.NET Core 1.0, 1.1 and in Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017.  If I use au new without the --here and no ASP.NET Core integration au run will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer buried in an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/405

The run.js file need to also have the path updated.

```
baseDir: ['./wwwroot'],
```